# King of Tokyo: Poison Quills

Tags: king-of-tokyo

The Poison Quills card says

```
When you roll 2 2 2 or more, add 2 damage to your Roll.
```

Does that mean `2 2 2 2` or also `3 3 3`?[image]

Comment: usually more implies more dice of the same type... no over the number...

Comment: Can you give the complete text of the card?  That doesn't seem like the full text of the card.

Comment: Added the exact text in question to make it more clear.

Comment: Wow what version is this from? Not only is the first part wording different, the effect itself is actually completely different!

Comment: Now I'm wondering if poison quills can be interpreted in some printings to be able to contribute to activating berserk mode (requires rolling 4 claws) from the Cybertooth expansion...  If quills adds two claws, I'd think it does.  If quills just adds two damage, I'd think it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

You need to roll at least three 2s; it doesn't matter if you roll more 2s.

There are a couple different wordings used depending on your version/printing; other versions do not say "or more". One version I found just states "when you score 2 2 2".

So the text applies when you are scoring three 2s.

Answer (score -1):

I have the Spanish version and it says `2 2 2 o superior` which makes it sound more like `3 3 3` than `2 2 2 2` (otherwise they would have translated it to `o más`.

Also if it was `2 2 2 2+` then I don't think they would need to mention the `or more`. Just `2 2 2` would be enough.

Same for other cards that say `1 1 1 o superior` so `2 2 2` or `3 3 3`.